# How do I solve HTTP request error (404 Not Found) for react project?

Tags: http, nginx

I made a project using react and mysql for user authentication. I am trying to send HTTP request for user sign up and log in. It was working fine when I tested on my local device in localhost. However, when I deployed it using Nginx, I am getting this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

This is the code I have for this command: `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/todo.hojungkimm`:

```
`server {

    root /home/john/TODO-App/client/build;
    index index.html;

 server_name todo.hojungkimm.com; # Dont do www if subdomain

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /server {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/todo.hojungkimm.com/fullchain.pem; # >
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/todo.hojungkimm.com/privkey.pem; >
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
Server {
if ($host = todo.hojungkimm.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;

    server_name todo.hojungkimm.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}`
```

And I also made sure port 8000 is active using this command: `sudo netstat -tuln`:
`tcp6 0 0 :::8000 :::* LISTEN`

I have attached the GitHub repository and the website below:

https://github.com/hjjyhj/TODO-App
https://todo.hojungkimm.com/

This is what I have on .env file on client:REACT_APP_SERVERURL=https://todo.hojungkimm.com/server

Also, I am running server.js with pm2.
It's Auth.js that's sending the HTTP request. Could anyone please help me solve this problem?